# What is the correct semantic HTML5 tag for placing an ad in?

Tags: ads

I know that much of HTML5 is about better semantics for specifying to crawlers (as well as screen readers) what type of content is contained within the tag.  Is there a correct semantic tag for placing an advertisement in?

My best guess is the `<aside>` tag...but I'm not sure about that.  I'm also thinking that maybe there isn't one, because such a tag, would not only allow for webmasters to "take inventory" for purposes of displaying ads, but it would also allow people who didn't want to see the ads to filter them out using a browser plugin.

Comment: Assuming you're serving ads from one of the major ad domains, using a common tag won't really matter for the purposes of ad blocking. People who want to block ads already use things like AdBlock Plus and NoScript to blacklist advertisers. If you're regularly serving ads yourself it might matter, but it's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: @Desidero That's wasn't the question.  It's not for purposes of ad blocking, it's for purposes of whatever spider shows up on the site and needs to differentiate between the ads and the content.

Comment: Wow I guess nobody knows I asked this in 2012.

Comment: That's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. I don't know that there is a "correct" answer for this.

Comment: This was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14405396/1503127.  In summary, you're right. w3c specifies that <aside> can also be used for advertising