# HTML element for ad?

Tags: html, naming-conventions, ads, semantic-markup

Is there any authoritative information on the web concerning which HTML element to chose for an advertisement banner?

I considered `<article>` or `<aside>`, but I think more appropriate is simply: `<div class="ad">`

Comment: Just as long as it's static, so AdBlock can find it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases I'd use the [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element):

> The element can be used for […] for **advertising**, […] and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.

As the `aside` element is a sectioning element, it creates an entry in the document outline, even if you don't use a heading explicitly. In most cases this would be what you want.

---

If you don't host the ad yourself, you might want to include it in [`iframe`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element):

> Here is an example of a page using an `iframe` to include **advertising** from an advertising broker:
>
> ```
> <iframe src="http://ads.example.com/?customerid=923513721&amp;format=banner"
>     width="468" height="60"></iframe>
> ```

(Where appropriate use the [`sandbox` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) for security.)

---

So, a simple blog post page could be structured like:

```
<body>

  <h1>My blog</h1>

  <article>
    <h1>My blog post</h1>
    <p>…</p>
  </article>

  <nav>
    <h1>Navigation</h1>
    <!-- site-wide navigation -->
  </nav>

  <aside>
    <h1>Advertisement</h1> <!-- or omit the heading altogether, it doesn't change the outline -->
    <iframe></iframe>
    <footer><small>Advertisement by ACME Inc.</small> <!-- or whatever --> </footer>
  </aside>

</body>
```

The page has the following [outline](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/):

> 1. My blog
>
>    1. My blog post
>    2. Navigation
>    3. Advertisement

Comment: The W3C definitely is an authoritative source. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no HTML element defined to mean advertisement banner. In HTML5, `<aside>` means “tangentially related” content, which is quite different, and `<article>` is even more different. Whether you use `<div class="ad">` or something else depends on what you expect to achieve. There is normally no reason to use any specific markup for ads.